# AttributeError: 'QgsVectorLayer' object has no attribute 'setCacheImage'

Tags: python, error, qgs, qgsvectorlayer

When I call the following (using QGIS 3.0.2):

```
self.layerCatalog =  QgsCore.QgsVectorLayer( "MultiPolygon?%s" % s_fields, nameLayer, "memory")

if self.iface.mapCanvas().isCachingEnabled():
        self.layerCatalog.setCacheImage(None)
```

I get the error "AttributeError: 'QgsVectorLayer' object has no attribute 'setCacheImage'"

setCacheImage is a function in the parent class QgsMapLayer in QGIS 2. It is not there in QGIS 3. Looking at the Backwards Incompatible Changes site [here](https://qgis.org/api/api_break.html), I do not see where it was moved or renamed. Anyone know?

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the answer. Via the [Deprecated List](https://qgis.org/api/2.18/deprecated.html), "since 2.4 - caches listen to repaintRequested() signal to invalidate the cached image". Apparently calling [triggerRepaint(True)](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsMapLayer.html) will emit repaintRequested with defferUpdate set to True. I believe that would do the same thing?